# C programming - 2d multidimensional array throwing error - Segmentation Fault

Tags: multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i,j,k,n;
n=1000;

int a[n][n];  
int b[n][n];   
int c[n][n];


int r = 0;



/* code segment */
for (k=0; k<n; k++){
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){ 
                        r = a[i][k];
            for (j=0; j<n; j++){
                      c[i][j] += r + b[k][j];
            }// end for…j) 
        }// end for…i)
}// end for…k)

return 0;   
}//end main
```

> whenever i run the code with n=1000 it throws segmentation error but
>   it works fine for n=100. It will be great if someone can tell me what
>   goes wrong.

Comment: Because your arrays are never initialized. As a result, you're assigned rubbish (`a[i][k]`) to `r`, and you're adding `r` + rubbish (`b[k][j]`), which at some point will result in a segfault.

Comment: Why does this work with `n=100`? Luck. Often, when not compiled with optimizations, there's quite a lot of zeroed memory around that you can run into (I don't know if the compiler somehow does that), so all elements in `b` happen to be 0. With 1000x1000 arrays, you'll be running into "bad" areas of random memory.

Comment: Actually, a note on my second comment: 3 100x100 arrays of int (4 bytes) probably fit into stack memory. 3 1000x1000 arrays of int (about 11.4 MB) very likely do not fit into the stack, but into heap memory. I don't know all the differences between stack and heap memory, but it looks like from your experiment, that stack memory is a bit "safer" to use.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the code but can you give example of how i can declare 2d array in heap memory and probably allocate 1000x1000 arrays of int in it.

Comment: I was able to run the program by initializing the arrays globally. So @Evert thanks anyway for looking into the issue it is resolved now.

Comment: The array *is* automatically declared in heap memory (likely) if it doesn't fit in stack memory; no need to do anything different for that. And you don't need to initialize the arrays globally, just inside the relevant function (after declaring them).

Comment: For (large) arrays, however, you could change to use calloc/malloc/free instead, though.